# Boolean simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify the following expression:

```
(x+ ~x)~(~(~z xor y) + (yx))
   (1)~(~(~z xor y) + (yx))
   ~(~(~z xor y) + (yx))
   (~z xor y) + ~(yx)
   (~z xor y) + (~y + ~x)
   (~y~z + yz) + (~y + ~x) <---- im stuck here
```

How can I simplify this more? and once it is simplified how do i calculate the number of gate delays

Comment: Following FabioSomenzi's answer, you get $x' + yz + y' + y'z'$ which is equal to $x' +yz + y'z'$, and I'm not seeing any further simplification here...

Comment: @amrsa Check your use of absorption.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Right, I meant is equal to $x' + yz + y'$ and this in turn equals $x' + y' + z$ (because, in general, $a+a'b = a + b$). Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $+$ is both associative and commutative, which allows you to drop parentheses and rearrange terms.